# angularjs + mongolab $http.put doesn't update model

Tags: http, angularjs, crud, put, mlab

I'm just getting started with angular and coding in general so bear with me...

I'm currently trying to write a basic phonebook-like CRUD app. So far, I have no trouble adding and viewing contacts, but I'm stuck on how to **update** my model on MongoLab via `$http.put` and MongoLab's API

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my UpdateCtrl function and related form attached (placed a generic URL here for demonstration purpose):

### controller.js

```
function UpdateCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location){
$scope.contactId = $routeParams.contactId;

var url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/databases/<d>/collections/<c>/<id>;

$http.get(url).
    success(function(mongoDataById) {
        $scope.contact = mongoDataById;
    });

$scope.updateContact = function() {
    $http.put(url, $scope.contact);
    };
}
```

### update.html (partial view)

```
<form ng-submit="updateContact()">

    <label for="fullname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullname" ng-model="contact.fullname" ><br/>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" ng-model="contact.email"><br/>

    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" ng-model="contact.phone"><br/>

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

---

### edit

@Stewie and @Arun P Johny, there do not seem to be any errors in the console when I execute updateContact(). I suspect it is sending a PUT request with the same data resulting from the initial GET request, even though changes have been made in the form in the current $scope. (And yes, I have a specific contactId in my Url - tested in browser, and it pulls the data for specific contact I've selected)

@pkozlowski.opensource - yeah I actually added that library when I started on this project, but when I was able to get away with fairly simple $http POST and GET functions, I felt like it wasn't necessary. Might give it a try now if I can't figure out using the basic $http.put.

Comment: So, what happens when `updateContact` is called? Does it send a request to the correct API endpoint? Do you have any errors in your console? Do you specify contact ID in your PUT url?

Comment: It could be because of the same origin policy, if you inspect the console can you find any errors

Comment: mongolab does not support jsonp, so i think the only solution is to use CORS support somehow, I haven't done it though

Comment: You might want to check this project: https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab-promise that makes working with MongoLab in AngularJS considerably easier. It also includes support for PUT (update) requests.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource just reworked my app using mongolab-promise. And works great now! Took a bit of rewiring of my module and how routing was set up, but finally got it working.

Comment: @bahrieinn glad you have it working!

Answer (score 0):

You might need an API key in order to access Mongo Lab's RESTful API such as:

```
GET /databases/{database}/collections/{collection}
```

Example listing all documents in a given collection:

```
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey
```

Optional parameters
[q=][&c=true][&f=][&fo=true][&s=][&sk=][&l=]

More info at:
http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/#authentication

It would be nice if you could tell us if Get commant works correctly